# How is it possible to deduce $A$ from $A\wedge B$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If I know that $A\wedge B = T$  then I can say that surely $A$ and $B$ **separately** are true, but if $A\wedge B = F$ then how can I infer the truth value of $A$ or the one of $B$. It seems impossible to infer the result : I can say just that  $¬A∨¬B = T$. What am I missing? Am i misuderstanding the process of making deductions?

**EDIT:**

Is it linked to the fact that $A\wedge B\implies A$ is a tautology? Because this is the reason given in my book. Should I consider just the case $A\wedge B = T$ ?

Comment: All you can infer is $\lnot A \lor \lnot B$.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the statement of implication. implications of the form $p->q$ are read as "if p is then q is true", which is the case if and only if the proposition $p->q$ is true. But if $p->q$ is true and $p$ is false then $q$ is either true or false. Substitute $p=A ∧ B$ and $q = A$ and think again you shall get your answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If (A $\land$ B) is false, then inferring either A or B is not valid.  In general, inferring anything from a false premise is not valid, though there do exist exceptions such as if (A <-> B) is false, and B is false, then A is true.

Often enough though, in formal systems, it's required that a formula holds true for inferences to get made from it (and the rule of inferences used always preserve truth also).  That's one reason why the axiomatic method has something to recommend to it, and sometimes gets regarded as more rigorous.

Comment: Thank you ! Can you elaborate a bit more on the second part? Because I'm struggling to get a good understanding of it

Comment: @Tortar The second part refers to soundness.  That means that all axioms are tautologies, and all rules of inference preserve truth.  Thus, any correct deduction of formulas in the formal system will produce only tautological formulae.

Comment: ok , but why , then, even if $A \wedge B \implies A$ is a tautology and I know $A \wedge B$ I can't say anything on $A$ ?

Comment: @Tortar If you know that (A$\land$B), then (A$\land$B) is true.  So, then you can say that A is true.

Comment: So have I Always to consider ' I know $A \wedge B$ ' to mean  ' I know $A \wedge B$  is true' ?

Comment: I don't know, maybe the only way to understand such sentences for me it's to substitute $\implies$ with $\subset$

Comment: @Tortar You do have to consider (A$\land$B) to hold true, yes.

Comment: Of course the inference remains VALID even if the premiss is false: valid arguments can have false premisses. Doug Spoonword means the argument isn't SOUND (i.e. it doesn't BOTH have a true premiss and proceed by a valid inference step). The distinction is crucial.

Comment: @PeterSmith According to second definition of Merriam-Webster's dictionary 'valid' means: "well-grounded or justifiable": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/valid  So, the above use of 'valid' is, as one might say, valid.  Though, yes, if a 'valid argument' gets defined as one which where it's impossible for the premises to hold true, and the conclusion to be false, then assuming (A $\land$ B) is false is valid.  But, it's not well-grounded or justifiable to say that anything can get inferred from (A $\land$ B).  Truth preservation is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the truth-table is helpful for $A \wedge B$
$$
\begin{matrix}
A & B & A \wedge B \\ \hline
F & F & F \\
F & T & F \\
T & F & F \\
T & T & T 
\end{matrix}
$$
If you know that $A \wedge B=F$, it could be any of the first three cases.  So you cannot infer $A$'s state or $B$'s state, but you can infer that one of them is false.

Comment: I edited to better explain where the question comes from

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Morgan Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), all that you can deduce from knowing $A\wedge B=F$ is that 
$$\neg (A\wedge B)=\neg F=T \Longrightarrow \boxed{(\neg A)\vee (\neg B)=T}$$

Comment: I edited to better explain where the question comes from

Answer (score 1):

Now the rules of inference are based on intuition, and their application and development dates long back.

Now if you see a proposition as $A ∧ B$ then at the back of our mind we shall be working that that this said proposition is true.( So it's the convention followed in many textbooks, if $p$ is a proposition, we prove a theorem: $p$, where the extension 
"that $p$ is true is implicit")

Now if  $A ∧ B$ it means that in our hand both $A$ and $B$ are true and again going by the convention, "are true" is implicit

So intuitively we have:

$(A ∧ B) \implies A$

Now we can use hardcore mathematics such as boolean algebra and truth-table proof as the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the very definition of deductive validity: An argument or inference is deductively valid if and only if it is the case that if the premise(s) is/are **true**, then the conclusion is true. And indeed, if $A \land B$ is true, then $A$ has to be true as well, and so you can indeed infer $A$ from $A \land B$. The case where $A \land B$ is false is simply not of interest in asking whether $A$ follows from $A \land B$ or not.